# Should I use jQuery Templates?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-templates

I have a page where search results are loaded from an XHR response.  What are the advantages of using [jQuery templates](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/) to display search results in this situation, rather than using a more conventional approach with .html() or .load()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using templates allow you to keep a lot of escaped markup outside of Javascript code. Most Javascript solutions now use the technique (first documented, as far as I know, by [John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/)): you put the template markup inside a `script` tag with a `type` attribute set to `text/html` (or some other content-type unrecognized by the browser `text/tmpl`, `text/jstmpl`, whatever).

As for the specific choice of [jQuery templating](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl), this is a matter of some discussion. For a while it looked like that code was going to become a part of the core jQuery code, but apparently that's off the agenda.

(There are many alternative templating libraries, though -- personally I like [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) because it's been ported to many languages besides Javascript, which I find useful.)

Answer (score 2):

The main advantages are:

- Using a template engine makes it easy to separate out what's being displayed from how it's being displayed.
- You can reuse templates, if you need them in different scenarios

The main disadvantage of a javascript templating engine is the overhead of execution, but it's only a problem if your template is big.

Hope this helps. 
Cheers